# Proof that $x+(-x)=0$ for surreal numbers

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, surreal-numbers

This is from Conway's on numbers and games:

$x+(-x)=0$. We have to show $x+(-x)\geq 0$ and $x+(-x )\leq 0$.  If say $(x+(-x))\ngeq 0$, we should have some $(x+(-x))^R\leq 0$, that is $x^R+(-x)\leq 0$ or $x+(-x)^L\leq 0$. But these are false, since we have by induction $x^R+(-x)^R\geq 0$, $x^L+(-x)^L\geq 0$.

I know that $x^R+(-x)\leq 0$ is a right option of $(x+(-x))$ so if its negative the number is. I don't understand where the "or $x+(-x)^L\leq 0$" come from.
And why do we have $x^R+(-x)^R\geq 0$, $x^L+(-x)^L\geq 0$ by induction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Where does $x+(-x)^L\le0$ come from?

It is a typo that your question has that my copy of the book does not, possibly related to confusion about notational conventions.

My copy says $x+-x^L$, not $x+(-x)^L$. This is because the right options of $x+(-x)$, that is, the ones denoted by "$(x+\,-x)^R$" in the book, have either the form $x^R+(-x)$ or the form $x+(-x)^R$. And by the definition of $-x$, something like $(-x)^R$ is like $-(x^L)$. By the conventions related to order of operations in regular arithmetic (since exponentiation has higher precedence than multiplication by $-1$), we write $-x^L$ to mean $-(x^L)$ and not $(-x)^L$.

#### Why do we have things by induction?

This is related to the paragraph just before PROPERTIES OF ORDER AND EQUALITY.

> ...note that almost all our proofs are inductive...we feel free to suppress all references to these inductive hypotheses

In this case, the implied inductive assumption is that $y+\,-y\ge0$ is true for all of the options of $x$, so that $x^R+\,-x^R\ge0$ and $x^L+\,-x^L\ge0$.

#### Where's the rest of the proof?

In case it wasn't clear, when the book says "say, $x+\,-x\ngeq0$", it's implying that we're only proving $x+\,-x\ge0$ and that the proof of $\le0$ is analogous.

Comment: Why does $x^L+-x^L\geq 0$ imply $x+-x^L\leq0$ is false?

Comment: by doing algebra on them as if they were real numbers it follows from $x \geq x^L$ but we havent shown we're allowed to do that yet.

Comment: Like we haven't shown we can add to both sides of an inequality; this is shown after

Comment: @why There's no algebra involved, just the definition of $\le $. By definition, $a\le b $ iff $\text{no } b^R\le a$ and $b\le \text{no }a^L $. So by contrapositive, $a\nleq b $ iff $\text{some }b^R\le a $ or $b\le \text{some }a^L $. Here we have $a=x+\,-x^L $, $b=0$, and the relevant $ \text{some }a^L$ being $x^L+\,-x^L $. As an aside, for a more explicit introduction to the Surreals, I recommend looking at ["Surreal Numbers" by Claus Tøndering](https://www.tondering.dk/download/sur16.pdf).